# Node.js page transition no more working when I use AngularJS $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I use Node.js as a server it's completely working well unless I add AngularJS to the stack, which broken completely all of my URL in Node.js. Specifically, I want to toggle the `active` of my tabs in Bootstrap 3 navigation bar with response to the tap of the tab, but I want AngularJS only to toggle the active/inactive of the tab, and don't want AngularJS to stand in anything others, which I want Node to manage.

So here's my code in Angular:

```
"use strict";

var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]);
MyApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when("/contact", {controller: MyCtrl}).
        when("/blog", {controller: MyCtrl});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
}]);
```

And controller code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact')}"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I tap any tabs from within my Chrome browser, the toggle can work properly - for example, when I tap Blog tab then it's active in Bootstrap 3 navbar. However, the page doesn't make transition properly, so the actual Blog contents cannot be displayed on the screen - all that it changes is the tab toggle.

Things are even worse, that when I tap on another contents on my screen, which is outside of the control of the Bootstrap 3 navbar, then it still makes the transition broken, and the page still remains to be a pre-tapped state.

So how can I correctly make the page transition to the correct page, and have Angular to only toggle the active/inactive status of the navbar's tab? I don't use AngularJS template and want only it to control the toggle functionality.

Note that even if the transition by tap doesn't work, when I type in the URL to the window of the browser and push return key, then the transition does work properly. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AngularJS with `ngRoute` means that AngularJS will attempt to handle all your routing requirements, however you can get by without it.  To leave route handling up to Node:

- Do away with your `ngRoute` dependency and then remove your `.config` section altogether.
- Remove `$routeParams` from your controller
- In your pages (handled by Node) you will need to add `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` to your body elements.

`$location` should now work fine to just update your tab classes.  If not, use `$window.location.pathname` instead.

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm. As to the `$location`, when I injected it the page is not refreshed automatically. So I used `$window.location.pathname`. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: And one more question - is it not feasible to use `ngRoute` and still leave the routing to the backend like Node at the same time? Maybe if I set a template in `$routeProvider` it works but it cannot be implemented without a template, right?

Comment: You can use `ngRoute` to pull data from the backend by using `templateUrl` with `$routeProvider`, but this method expects only partial pages to be delivered from the backend.  Check out the example in docs (right down the bottom) for more details: [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)